# remove stubborn first space of string in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, space

Ok I am trying to remove a very stubborn space from the beginning of my string using regex. 
This string is being parsed from a CSV file into Perl using the Text:CSV module and when I print a Dumper of the string I get:

```
$VAR1 = ' Mgmt-General-Other';
```

now I have tried to use Regex to remove this space, someone will tell me to use:

```
$string =~ s/\s+$//;
```

I have already tried this as well as:

```
$string =~ s/\s//g;
```

and

```
$string =~ s/^\s//g;
```

and none of these worked, the middle one pulled every space out of everything except for the one I wanted. I'm trying to loop through a 2,000 line CSV file so I'd rather make this automated and not have to make a special case for this one weird instance.

Is there any way that this character at the beginning is not a space or a white space? Or how can I take it out?

Adding more things that I have tried;

```
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
```

here is my code:

```
my @value = @columns[1..12];
my $string = @value[9];
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
$string =~ s/\s+$//;
print Dumper $string;
```

if it matters these are my declarations at the top of the script:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Long;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;
```

Comment: `@value[9]` -> `$value[9]`. What does `pring $string` give, btw?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am slightly confused by what you are asking, I tried changing `@value[9]` to `$value[9]` but to no avail.

Comment: Try `print join ':', map ord, split //, $string` line - and paste output into your question, please.

Comment: this returned: `160:77:103:109:116:45:71:101:110:101:114:97:108:45:79:116:104:101:114`

Comment: I see now. ) Will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, so I had another character that wasn't displayed because it was an uncommon character? Is this correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13967/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-natesholland)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were pretty close actually, as the correct regex for replacing whitespace at the *beginning* of the string would be:

```
$sting =~ s/^\s+//;
```

As for other solutions:

```
$sting =~ s/\s+$//; # the same as 'rtrim', removes whitespace at the end of the string
$sting =~ s/\s//g;  # will just remove all whitespace
$sting =~ s/^\s//g; # will remove single whitespace symbol right at the beginning of the string.
```

UPDATE: turned out you had a `\xA0` (so-called 'non-breakable whitespace', which is NOT included in `\s`) in your string. ) Try this:

```
$sting =~ s/^[\s\xA0]+//;
```

Comment: Then, it might not be a space... It could be a tab character.

Comment: @NateSHolland Check [the demo](http://codepad.org/hhgfO90I), compare this code to yours.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but every solution you listed except for the end of the string thing is in my original question and I said I tried them and they didn't work. How would I pull a tab out?

Comment: @raina77ow I have the same code but it doesn't work for me for some reason. Any ideas why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Tab, as well as the plain space symbol, is contained within `\s` character class. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You are assuming that because you don't see an apparent character that is is whitespace.  What does this show?: `say ord substr $string,0,1`

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the fact that **there is no such thing as "just a string" anymore**.

The simplest solution is to make sure that you're using `unicode_strings` semantics with your regular expression.  You can achieve this one of several ways.  Again, going for simplicity, you could just turn it on at the beginning of your script:

```
use utf8;
use feature qw( unicode_strings );
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $string
    = join '', map { chr } ( 160,  77, 103, 109, 116,  45,
                              71, 101, 110, 101, 114,  97,
                             108,  45,  79, 116, 104, 101,
                             114 );

print $string, "\n";

$string =~ s/^\s+//;

print $string, "\n";
```

Another alternative is to just turn on `unicode_strings` semantics for the specific regular expression that is processing a Unicode string:

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $string
    = join '', map { chr } ( 160,  77, 103, 109, 116,  45,
                              71, 101, 110, 101, 114,  97,
                             108,  45,  79, 116, 104, 101,
                             114 );

print $string, "\n";

$string =~ s/^\s+//u;

print $string, "\n";
```

Another approach is to explicitly specify the Unicode property that encompasses all sorts of space characters, including those typically found in `\s`:

```
s/^\p{Space}//;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this because I don't see a *general* solution. This is what you need to do.

```
say ord( $string ); # prints out the numeric value of the character.

# In your case it would print out: 160

# OR

say sprintf( '\x{%x}', ord( $string )); # prints out \x{00} in hex

# In your case: \x{a0}
```

And cut and paste that into your substitution:

```
$string =~ s/^[\s\x{00}]//;
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove leading spaces, try: `$string =~ s/^\s+//;`

And this should remove leading tabs: `$string =~ s/^\t+//;`

Comment: This ignores the fact that the first character in the string that the OP is using has the Unicode "NO-BREAK SPACE" character, which won't be matched by \s unless the regex either uses the /u modifier, or unicode_strings is in effect.